# Ubuntu VM won't run when assigned more than one CPU in Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu

I've got a 64-bit ubuntu 16.04 VM running in Oracle VirtualBox 5.2.0 on a Windows 7 Pro host. The host has 12 physical cores (24 logical) so naturally I want to run my VM with more than one core!

The VM runs fine when assigned 1 CPU but it simply won't start if I assign it 2 or more CPUs. Note Oracle VirtualBox is happy to let me *assign* more than one CPU in its System > Processor settings. But when I try to start the VM I see ubuntu's GRUB menu, but then as soon as ubuntu starts booting the screen goes black with a flashing cursor in the top-left. And then nothing appears to happen... I can't see anything obvious in VBox.log for the VM.

Does anybody know how I can get the VM running with > 1 CPU?